# Automatically kill tmux session

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal

I use tmux, and everytime i open a terminal it create a new session and don't destroy the old one...
I have set the destroy-unattaced to on but at the tmux ls they are still here

Is it possible that when i close the window of the terminal the session is ended ?

Like i only have the session '0' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three different ways to do that. Try this one first:

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ ! -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    tmux kill-session -t 0
fi
    tmux new-session -s 0
```

Yes, it's too long, but it enables you to improve it.